# Ruby on rails skipping rest of block when assert_select fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, block

I've implemented internationalization support for a Rails application using the I18n module, and I am now testing this implementation.

I'm using functional tests with assert_select to assert that there are no span HTML elements with the class name "translation_missing", which works fine.

I've also written a helper method to get all the locale files from the config/locales directory, which works fine as well.

My problem is when I try to loop through each locale and check that there are no missing translations.  If the test fails for one locale, it exits the block, reporting the failure, whereas I would like the test to continue running and output multiple failure messages where applicable.  Here is the test:

```
test "index page no missing translations" do 

  # Login as admin to avoid 302 errors
  login_as(@user)

  # Get a list of the locales
  locales = get_locales()

  # Check each locale for missing translations
  locales.each do |locale|
  get :index, :locale => locale
  assert_select "span.translation_missing", false, "Broadcasts index page: Translations missing from #{locale}.yml"

  end
end
```

Is there any way that I can stop the block from being exited?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point of tests are for them to be understood what is working, and what isn't. I realize it can be cumbersome, but a test should test one thing. If you have a few different locals to expect to be correct on the index page, check them individually in tests. I'm not sure if there's a good automated way to do so.

Comment: My main reason for checking all the locales at once was so that any locales added in the future would be tested automatically - future maintainers can't be guaranteed to write test themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably metaprogram it away, e.g. something like (untested)

```
get_locales.each do |locale|
  test "index page translations #{locale}" do 
   # Login as admin to avoid 302 errors
   login_as(@user)
   get :index, :locale => locale
   assert_select "span.translation_missing", false, "Broadcasts index page: Translations missing from #{locale}.yml"
  end
end
```

This will result in creating multiple tests, each of which only tests one locale, and none is messing up with the results of the others.